# Elasticsearch NEST Reuse ElasticClient for different index query

Tags: elasticsearch, asp.net-core, dependency-injection, .net-core, nest

How can I register ElasticClient as singleton in a .NET Core application but still able to specify the different index during the query?

For example:

In Startup.cs I register an elastic client object as singleton, by only mentioning the URL without specifying the index.

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    ....
    var connectionSettings = new ConnectionSettings(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));
    var client = new ElasticClient(connectionSettings);
    services.AddSingleton<IElasticClient>(client);
    ....
}
```

Then when injecting ElasticClient singleton object above, I would like to use it for different indices in 2 different queries.

In the class below, I want to query from an index called "Apple"

```
public class GetAppleHandler
{   
    private readonly IElasticClient _elasticClient;

    public GetAppleHandler(IElasticClient elasticClient)
    {
        _elasticClient = elasticClient;
    }

    public async Task<GetAppleResponse> Handle()
    {
        // I want to query (_elasticClient.SearchAsync<>) using an index called "Apple" here
    }
}
```

From code below I want to query from an index called "Orange"

```
public class GetOrangeHandler
{   
    private readonly IElasticClient _elasticClient;

    public GetOrangeHandler(IElasticClient elasticClient)
    {
        _elasticClient = elasticClient;
    }

    public async Task<GetOrangeResponse> Handle()
    {
        // I want to query (_elasticClient.SearchAsync<>) using an index called "Orange" here
    }
}
```

How can I do this? If it's not possible, can you suggest other approach that will allow me to inject ElasticClient through .NET Core dependency injection and at the same time also allow me to query from 2 different indices of the same ES instance?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just need to specify the index on the request

```
var defaultIndex = "person";
var pool = new SingleNodeConnectionPool(new Uri("http://localhost:9200"));

var settings = new ConnectionSettings(pool)
    .DefaultIndex(defaultIndex)
    .DefaultTypeName("_doc");

var client = new ElasticClient(settings);

var searchResponse = client.Search<Person>(s => s
    .Index("foo_bar")
    .Query(q => q
        .Match(m => m
            .Field("some_field")
            .Query("match query")
        )
    )
);
```

Here the search request would be

```
POST http://localhost:9200/foo_bar/_doc/_search
{
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "some_field": {
        "query": "match query"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- `foo_bar` index has been defined in the search request
- `_doc` type has been inferred from the global rule on `DefaultTypeName("_doc")`